# Adding optional message in PDF

Tags: browser, pdf, javascript

Modern browsers support opening PDF files, but [my resume](https://r.venomvendor.com/download) is little complex for browsers & they don't render properly or sometimes display blank pages, hence am not getting shortlisted. The same works in Adobe Acrobat Reader or similar dedicated software.

I want to add a message **"Kindly use Adobe Acrobat Reader"**, if opened `ONLY` in browsers.

This has been achieved in the [this pdf](https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm5484e.pdf), showing:

[image: Please wait message]

Comment: Fix your resume. Complexity isn't good unless its serving a purpose, and as you've admitted your resume is so complex, the complexity itself is raising issues. Further, the PDF standard does not support this level of programmatic intelligence, so no, you cannot make such a message.

Comment: I've managed to downsize from 47MB to 1.5MB, couldn't improve further.

Comment: Size != complexity, but that's probably progress in a good direction.

Comment: Beware that your "this pdf" example only shows the _"If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF viewer may not be able to display this type of document."_ in Preview on macOS as well. (Same in Chrome, indeed.) Your question aside: if I were recruiting and got multiple responses, then I'd not install Adobe PDF just to read your resume, so that's a lost opportunity for you then. It will also fail automated parsing in recruitment software like used by many corporates.

Comment: What about renaming to something like _"Show message when PDF is opened in unsupported reader?"_ Also: does the "this pdf" example open fine in Adobe's reader? (I don't have that installed.) Adding a screenshot of the expected result might be nice.

Comment: I stress again, in other words, what said by other too. __The meaning to do a resume is to convince someone to hire you.__ There is nothing of kind to force someone to install a proprietary program to read your CV.  Creating such problems you will probably finish to lose the opportunity to be hired. Moreover, the backward compatibility is not a fancy stuff: PDF is a standard because you are able to read it regardless of the OS... (the _P means Portable_) and without changing the formatting. In this case, you should search for solutions to avoid or to solve problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example PDF you gave contains an interactive form, which might be why the
browser cannot display it.

This PDF contains code written in Acrobat JavaScript that is launched by the
startup event. Acrobat JavaScript is in all respects standard JavaScript,
with the distinction that it has access to the viewer and document DOM
with all the implied objects and methods.

Below is an image of the code contained in your example,
in the form of two JavaScript scripts, which produce the page whose image
you gave when the viewer does not support the required version 9 of PDF
or does not support [XFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFA).
This is in the form of an image, since the PDF viewer I'm using does not do
copy or export.

[[image: Click for a larger image]Click for a larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Ylo.jpg)

I cannot give explicit directions on how to create such a document,
but here are some useful references:

- [Adobe Applying actions and scripts to PDFs](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/applying-actions-scripts-pdfs.html)
- [The Acrobat JavaScript Console (Your best friend for developing Acrobat JavaScript)](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/javascript_console)
- [Instructions for Installing Folder Level Scripts (Automation Tools) and Plug-ins](https://www.pdfscripting.com/public/Installing_Automation_Tools.cfm)
- [JavaScript Support](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/features/javascript/)

Comment: which tool are you using to display PDF objects?

Comment: I used the trial version of [callas pdfToolbox](https://www.callassoftware.com/en/products/pdftoolbox).

Answer (score 2):

While some programming can be done when modifying a PDF file (mostly using paid and advanced versions of Adobe Acrobat Reader), what you ask for is not possible.

More so, I had downloaded and opened your resume both in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC and in Google Chrome and I see no difference between these two versions. Therefore, I strongly believe that the real culprit is the machine you were opening your resume, not the way you designed it (which I think it's great, by the way)

Comment: I have `Acrobat PRO DC`. Do you have any suggestion or links to add some snippet  to resume.

Comment: The resume opens fine in Preview on macOS as well. Of course, maybe I'm missing some fancy features?